# FREQUENT AVD Emulator Already Running Error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Every single time I'm developing in Android Studio my Emulator will crash maybe once. But after that crash, that's it, I usually have to restart my computer just to kill the "qemu-system-x86_64" process.

I have tried killing the process in Task Manager and command prompt - it doesn't work.

I've tried deleting the .lock folders in the AVD's directory, that also does not work, Windows prompt's me to "Try Again" each time.

I'm truly sick of this error because it happens every time I use Android Studio, has anyone encountered the same recurring error? Any fixes? Am I missing an AVD update or something? Any free alternatives to Android Studio (my preferred coding language for app dev is Java)?

I really do not want to have to keep restarting my computer after each minor emulator crash.

Comment: I suggest you wipe data of your emulator sometimes.there will be less problems if you do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by updating my Android Studio IDE and available Plug-ins. I had been ignoring those update messages, so I finally did it.